# How can I join one column in other table with Laravel?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, database

Actually I'm using Laravel API. I have two table one named owners and the other is Units that contain an attribute named unit_no. I want to display the values in the attribute unit_no in a dropdown list with reactJs. But I don't know how to do it in the back-end part.
This is my controller code:

```
   function addOwner(Request $request){
        $owner= new Owner();
        $owner->name=$request->input('name');
        $owner->email=$request->input('email');
        $owner->password=$request->input('password');
        $owner->telephone=$request->input('telephone');
        $owner->cin=$request->input('cin');
        $owner->presentAdress=$request->input('presentAdress');
        $owner->permenantAdress=$request->input('permenantAdress');
        $owner->file_path= $request->file('file')->store('owners');  
        $owner->save();
        return $owner;
    }
```

and this is my database:

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('owners', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('telephone');
            $table->string('cin');
            $table->string('presentAdress');
            $table->string('permenantAdress');
            $table->string('file_path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to use eloquent. First, if you want to do a join you need to add in one of the 2 tables a common attribute.
For example, in Units you add owner_id attribute.
In the Unit & Owner model, you will define the relations between the Owner and Unit table.

But for a join of the two tables once you add the common column to one of the 2 tables in the migrations from the controller you should do.

```
$join_table = DB::table('owner')
        ->join('units', 'owner.id', '=', 'units.owner_id');
```

from this point, you can even get just the column you need.

```
$column = $join_table->pluck('unit_no');
```

Anyway you should improve the question is not clear and it's not complete.